# How to manage SELECT data from 3 different table's using with JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 different table's.

1. driver

```
| id  | name |
|-----|------|
| 10  | abc  |
| 21  | xyz  |
```

2. booking

```
| id | driver_id | booking_amount |
|----|-----------|----------------|
| 1  | 10        |  250           |
| 2  | 10        |  150           |
| 3  | 21        |  200           |
| 4  | 21        |  300           |
```

3. income

```
| id | driver_id | credit | debit |   date   |
|----|-----------|--------|-------|----------|
| 1  | 10        | 100    |       | 1-1-2019 |
| 2  | 10        | 250    |       | 2-1-2019 |
| 3  | 10        |        | 200   | 3-1-2019 |
| 4  | 21        | 250    |       | 1-1-2019 |
| 5  | 21        | 400    |       | 2-1-2019 |
| 6  | 21        |        | 50    | 3-1-2019 |
```

- driver.id = booking.driver_id
- driver.id = income.driver_id

I have use this query >>

```
SELECT driver.*, sum(booking.total_booking_income) as total_income 
FROM driver
JOIN booking ON driver.id=booking.driver_id
GROUP BY driver.id
ORDER BY driver.id DESC
```

**Note** : but i am not able to add balance field in my this query.

i want to all driver records of income after group of booking and group of income by driver id like

```
| id | driver_id | driver_name | total_income | balance |
|----|-----------|-------------|--------------|---------|
| 1  | 10        | abc         | 400          | -250    | 
| 2  | 21        | xyz         | 500          | 100     |
```

Comment: I don't understand how you are calculating the balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming balance is the difference between the credit and the debit then:

```
SELECT d.*, sum(b.total_booking_income) as total_income,
       i.balance
FROM driver d JOIN
     booking b
     ON d.id = b.driver_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT i.driver_id,
             SUM(i.credit) - SUM(i.debit) as balance
      FROM income i
      GROUP BY i.driver_id
     ) i
     ON i.driver_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id, i.balance
ORDER BY d.id DESC;
```